# updating database and using data table and data adapter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, webforms

what is wrong with the following code? The database does not update and else{} gets executed always. The database does contain 1 row with the field password!

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string connectionString = @"Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = db1; Integrated Security = True";
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            String sql = "update table1 set password = 'hello'";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
        cnn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Password Reset Successful! Redirecting to Homepage!')", true);
                Response.Redirect("testlogin.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Invalid Details";
            }

    }
```

Comment: You can not fill table with update command. It does not make sense.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek what and how do i use to know whether the database got upated or not?

Comment: @chronicle I need to update database!

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally understood what's wrong. I didn't have to use dataadapter or datareader at all. Just used '''int x=command.executenonquery();'''